# How to set mapped value in h:inputText (JSF2)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, websphere-liberty

I have a List of fields in FormEntry class. The bean has a method to retrieve a field by its name:

```
public Field fieldEntryByFieldName(String name) {
}
```

Field class has "name" and "value" properties.

To set a the value property in a JSF2 form, I had the following code working in JBoss:

```
<h:inputText value="#{formProcessorView.formEntry.fieldEntryByFieldName('otherReason').value}"/>
```

When I've moved to Websphere Liberty Profile it stopped working. I get the following exception:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: value="#{formProcessorView.formEntry.fieldEntryByFieldName('email').value}": Property 'fieldEntryByFieldName' not found on type com.servengine.formprocessor.ejb.FormEntry
```

fieldEntryByFieldName is not a property, but a method. This works in JBoss and Eclipse validation won't show any warning on the syntax. F3 will even take me from the xhtml page to the java source code of the method, so as for JBoss and Eclipse, code is one.
Was this never meant to work or it's a bug in WAS Liberty JSF2 implementation?
Is there a workarround to solve this? (Is there a way to set  fieldEntryByFieldName('otherReason').value in a JSF Form h:inputText?

Thanks

Comment: What EL library version? It seems WebSphere ships an old one.

Comment: You might be running with EL below 2.2 where parameterized methods are disallowed.

Comment: Hello. Yes... Liberty supports old JSF 2.0. I'm not sure of which version of MyFaces, but probably 2.0.5 (!!).